# How to render a Doctrine Timestampable field in a Symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

What I'm trying to do is to set a "seoUpdatedAt" field when the "pageTitle" or "metaDescription" fields are modified.
In the same time I'd like to render the content of this field in my backoffice through the Symfony2 form component, without giving the possibility to edit the field value (because the value must be set up by the timestampable extension).

I tried to set up the field as *read_only* but the value doesn't update, and neither does the doctrine extension (as though it is being ignored and it makes sense).

I also tried to set the field as a *datetime single_text* but two problems arose:

1. the admin can manually change the value
2. right after the submit action takes place the value that is rendered appears to be the old datetime although it's been updated on the DB side, as though the value in the POST request is overwriting the DB value in the form rendering flow. refreshing the page without resubmitting the data shows the updated value (updated by the doctrine extension)

I finally tried with the *disabled* option but it's not working as expected.

A pinch of code:

```
// in my entity

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field={"pageTitle", "metaDescription"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="seo_updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $seoUpdatedAt;
```

And here the form:

```
// in my form type

$builder
    ->add('pageTitle', 'text', array('required' => false))
    ->add('metaDescription', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
    ->add(
        'seoUpdatedAt',
        'datetime',
        array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss',
            'required' => false
        )
    );
```

So, how do you suggest meeting the following requirements?

- the value shouldn't be manually editable
- the value must be always rendered with the updated value even after a form submission

Listener on Doctrine events? Listener on a form event? A new form type extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the timestampable field from the form. I render it fetching by the data directly from the pagination object.

In that way the application meets all the requirements:

- the datetime field is updated by the timestampable extension
- the datetime value is always rendered with its current value even after a form submission
- the datetime value can't be changed through the web interface

I hope this might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
in your entity add an empty setter method for $seoUpdatedAt:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field={"pageTitle", "metaDescription"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="seo_updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $seoUpdatedAt;

public function setSeoUpdatedAt(\DateTime $seoUpdatedAt)
{
    //empty
}
```

and in your form builder object add the 'by_reference' option in the seoUpdatedAt definition:

```
$builder
    ->add('pageTitle', 'text', array('required' => false))
    ->add('metaDescription', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
    ->add(
        'seoUpdatedAt',
        'datetime',
        array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss',
            'required' => false,
            'by_reference' => false,
        )
    );
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer but that's not working as expected. in that way the user still have the impression that can edit the data even if he can't. more important is that the rendered value is not being updated right after the form submission, and this breaks my BDD tests :-(

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide much sample code because I don't know Symfonie (I'm working with ZF).

Look at the `onPrePerstist` or `onPreUpdate` events:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

It goes something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class YourClass



/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updateChanged() {
    $this->updated = new \DateTime();
}
```

Whenever you update a field, it calls the pre* method and updates your column.

**Update:**

Why not something like:

```
public function setMetaDescription($metaDescription) {
    $this->metaDescription = $metaDescription;
    $this->setUpdatedAt    = new \DateTime();
}
```

So whenever the field gets  updated, it also updates the datetime column.

Comment: I need to change the *seoUpdatedAt* field only if the "pageTitle" or the "metaDescription" fields have been edited. I don't think this could be meet through the Doctrine lifecycle events. Am I wrong?

Comment: @fra_casula this is correct. I have suggested another approach in the updated answer.

Comment: I've already tried it and it doesn't meet all the expected behaviours :-) Thanks anyway